# PHP save huge amount of static variable

Tags: php, performance, select

I want to add two select lists to choose a city in my country (user chooses the state, then depending on that state chooses the city). I did find the list of all the cities in each province for my country, I succeeded to make a file for this. And what I want to ask you is : what is the best way to store those data on the server ? use a database, a file or just PHP arrays?

In the case of database, how should I organize data ?
In the case of file, which type ?

Thanks !

Comment: Whatever works best for you. If you need to *query* the data, especially against other data, the database is an obvious candidate. If you always need the complete list and otherwise don't do much with it, a PHP array literal is very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a database:

Table name: states

Table structure:

```
state_id UNSIGNED SHORTINT
state_name VARCHAR 100
```

Table name: cities

Table structure:

```
state_id UNSIGNED SHORTINT - to determine which state the city is in
city_id UNSIGNED SHORTINT
city_name VARCHAR 100
```

If you use a file, you could use CSV files.

Or you could just store it in a couple PHP arrays, but databases are nice!

Comment: Np, you may also want to put Auto Increment on states.state_id and cities.city_id

Answer (score 0):

In case of database simply create two tables.
1. Table with countries containing Id and name.
2. Table with cities containing ID name and country ID